# "Poems" or "poetry"

Tags: differences, poetry

Can *poems* and *poetry* be used interchangeably, or is that incorrect usage? In normal conversation, they are used as synonyms often.

Comment: A poem is a box that contains poetry.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To me *poetry* is a literary art. A *poem* is a **piece of poetry**.

Comment: Poetry can also be a piece of a poem.

Comment: @ jwpat7: Would you have an example of *poetry* used as a countable noun then? I have always seen *poetry* used as uncountable and thought a sentence like  *I'm reading **a** poetry by Keats*? would not be acceptable.

Comment: Re your question, I don't have an example. Re your example, I agree that "a poetry" is a mistake.  What I meant by my remark is that "poetry" can be correctly used to refer to part of a poem; for example, a critic could properly say "There are five lines of poetry in this lengthy poem," or "There is no poetry to be found in this poem".

Comment: Let's not forget **Poesy**: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/poesy

Answer (score 12):

*Poetry* refers to the art form itself. *Poems* means multiple instances of that art form.

Their use can overlap, but there are some instances when only one is appropriate.

> *Poetry is notoriously difficult*.

This means that the art form is difficult to master, i.e., that it is hard to **write** poetry.

> *These poems are notoriously difficult*.

This means that the poems under discussion are hard to **understand**.

Here, though, they are essentially interchangeable:

> *Whitman's poetry focuses on nature.*

or

> *Whitman's poems focus on nature.*

My advice would be to **use the word *poetry* when speaking about the art itself, and *poems* when you have a specific set of poems in mind**. This will avoid any confusion.

Comment: Good distinction/advice, but I can imagine a writer (of both prose and poetry) saying *I find poems/poetry more demanding*, where both words would mean exactly the same, as in your *Whitman* examples. In the other examples, the question of whether it's the author or the reader who has difficulty isn't really relevant to the *poetry/poems* word-choice. Plus the first one could just as well have been **This** *poetry is notoriously difficult*.

Comment: Yes, good point(s). Though if someone said to me "This poetry is notoriously difficult", I might give them a weird look. It would sound to me like "this whole poetry thing is...", rather than "these poems are...".

Comment: Thank you! This makes more sense, now. I see them used interchangeably in informal writing and speech, but whether they ought to be interchangeable is where the problem lies. They should be distinct, but they aren't always used properly.

Answer (score 1):

It depends somewhat on the context; *poetry* can mean one or more *poems*, but in more figurative usages such as *poetry in motion*, meaning something outstanding or beautiful about a bird in flight, or a motorcycle race (as your tastes dictate), one wouldn't replace that with *poems in motion*, which would sound ridiculous.

These links to [poetry](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poetry) and [poem](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/poem) might help.

Answer (score 0):

Do you like poems? / Do you like poetry?

Here the sense is the same. Normally poetry is a genre of literature, beside narrative literature (novels) and theatre plays.  Shakespeare's shall I compare thee to a summer's day? as a single text is a poem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Poetry is the use of words and language to evoke a writer’s feelings and thoughts, while a poem is the arrangement of these words.
2. Poetry is the process of creating a literary piece using metaphor, symbols and ambiguity, while a poem is the end result of this process.

Comment: This post would be improved by explaining *why* you define the terms this way, for example, by providing a dictionary definition or examples in the wild. I encourage you take the site [tour] and review the [help] for additional guidance.

Answer (score -1):

Poetry and poem are definitely to become a marry. poetry means the people who start to write a poem, but poem is the language that had been writing to become a complete poem.

Comment: "To become a marry"? Can you please explain what you mean.

Comment: Poetry does not mean people who start to write a poem. That is a queer idea. And your definition of poem is queer, too.